# PHP, need file to be overwritten or deleted after use

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have written a function to get a file from S3 and get the number of pages from it. (It's a PDF.) Everything works fine until I try and do the same for multiple files.  Now it is just returning the number of pages of the last file. I think that the problem is that local.pdf needs to be deleted or overwritten, but I'm not sure how.  I thought it would automatically overwrite it.

I tried using `$pdf->cleanUp();` but that doesn't seem to do anything. It is still returning the page count of the last file.

This is the function that gets called for each child job:

```
public function getPageCountPDF($jobid) {
    $this->load->library('Awss3', null, 'S3');
    $PdfTranscriptInfo = $this->MJob->getDOCCSPdfTranscript($jobid);
    $filename = $PdfTranscriptInfo['origfilename'];
    $PdfFilename = 'uploads/' . $jobid . '/' . $filename;
    $localfilename = FCPATH . 'tmp\local.pdf';
    $this->S3->readfile($PdfFilename, false, 'bucket');
    require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdf.php';
    require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdi.php';
    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($localfilename);
    $pdf->cleanUp();
    return $pageCount;
}
```

I am not getting any error messages, but the $pageCount should be 8 and then 6. The return I am getting from the function is 6 and 6.

I also tried adding

```
    ob_clean();
    flush();
```

But that clears the whole page, which I don't want.

I also tried using a generated name instead of local.pdf, but that doesn't work (I get a "cannot open file" message).

**EDIT:** This is the part that calls the function getPageCountPDF($jobid):

```
foreach ($copies as $copy) {
    .
    .
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $pageCount = $CI->getPageCountPDF($copy['jobid']);
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: `This is the function that gets called for each child job:` instead you could shown that code part.

Comment: @RasaMohamed, I added it to my question.

Comment: If i may ask you have multiple files you want to read?

Comment: @joash, yes. I am testing now with 2, but there could be more. It looks at each child job, finds the file for it and gets the number of pages.

Comment: Can i post a procedure to get the all directory files and loop while reading each? then you can  delete what do you think?

Comment: Did u checked using `unset($pdf);` [UNSET](https://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Comment: @joash, sure. Thank you.

Comment: @RasaMohamed, I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for delay i had to test it try it and see

Comment: @RasaMohamed, I tried using `unset($pdf);` but there's no change.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function get_all_directory_files($directory_path) {
    $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory_path), array(
        '..',
        '.'
    ));

    return custom_shuffle($scanned_directory);
}
```

---

```
function custom_shuffle($my_array = array()) {
$copy = array();
while (count($my_array)) {
    // takes a rand array elements by its key
    $element = array_rand($my_array);
    // assign the array and its value to an another array
    $copy [$element] = $my_array [$element];
    // delete the element from source array
    unset($my_array [$element]);
}
return $copy;
```

}

So you can call **get_all_directory_files** which calls **custom_shuffle**

Then you can loop through while reading them. In case you want to delete the files

You can proceed with :

```
 $arrayfiles = get_all_directory_files('mypath');
    foreach ($arrayfiles as $filename) {
        echo 'mypath/'.$filename;  //You can do as you please with each file here
       // unlink($filename); if you want to delete
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is already a function that gets the file from each job. There should only be one PDF per child job. I have echoed out the files through the loop and the code is getting the correct files. It's getting messed up when I get the number of pages.

Comment: How about you change the read write permissions and you overwrite the file?

Comment: Using chmod? I will try that.

Comment: Yes like chmod("/somedir/somefile", 777); for read write and delete then you unlink or delete

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Where should I put the chmod line?

Comment: Had make an edit where after looping it check the permissions then deletes or  makes it deletable then deletes. Kindly give feed back if it works

Comment: I am getting an error message: chmod(): No such file or directory. I think that the file is not being written to start with. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194762/discussion-between-joash-and-riva-portman).

Answer (score 0):

What happens to $pageCount after
`$pageCount = $CI->getPageCountPDF($copy['jobid']);` ?
This gets overwritten after each iteration. Maybe you want something like `$pageCount[$copy['jobid']] = $CI->getPageCountPDF($copy['jobid']);` so you actually keep an array of $pageCounts to be processed further down the line.

Comment: $pageCount is in a loop that displays the child jobs, so it only gets called when a child job is to be displayed. It then gets compared to the number of pages that's been entered in the database and, if there is a difference, it's displayed with a red background. The array of $pageCounts is an idea though, thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Actually, the array won't work because as each child job is being called and displayed, the function is called to get the number of pages of the PDF in that job. It should then go to the next child job (when it's to be displayed) and find the number of pages in the PDF for that job.